# Are there any functions which were proposed as elementary by mathematicians but not considered elementary now?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, real-analysis

Are there any functions which were proposed by various mathematicians to be included in the set of elementary functions because of their properties but not considered elementary as of now?

Comment: There have been many functions used over the years.  Some of them are well-known and would be accepted if we asked for "closed form".  But the name "elementary function" has a well-established meaning, which has not changed since Liouville.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I think, it changed since Liuville. By Liuville, any inverse of a polynomial is elementary. By modern notions, not.

Comment: I disagree.  Modern treatments include "algebraic extension" among the steps allowed for elementary functions.  Example ... Bronstein, *Symbolic Integration I: Transcendental Functions*, Springer, 2004